# perl WWW::Mechanize secure login launch in browser

Tags: perl, cookies, authentication, mechanize

I am trying to auto-login to a website using this script:

```
use WWW::Mechanize;
use LWP;

my $company = 'company';
my $password = 'password';

my $mech = WWW::Mechanize->new();
my $url = 'https://www.infokeeper.com';

$mech->get($url);
$mech->form_name('GetLogin');
$mech->field('company', $company);
$mech->field('password', $password);                                                                                          
$mech->click('SubmitButton');

$mech->save_content("content.html");

my $url2 = $mech->uri;
system("chromium-browser \"$url2\"");
```

It does login successfully, evidenced by opening `content.html`. However, when I try to launch the "live" page in a browser using

```
my $url2 = $mech->uri;
system("chromium-browser \"$url2\"");
```

it gives the same validation error as if I had just clicked the "Submit" button without entering the username/password. What could be causing this? Something with the cookies?

Comment: Yes, the cookies aren't share between mech and chromium. What are tou trying to do with chromium ?

Comment: I don't necessarily need to use Chromium, I just need to open the page in a browser in the end so I can see the end result of where the automation took me. The script only shows the first step of what I ultimately want it to do, but in any event I need to launch the logged in page in a browser.

Comment: Mech IS a browser, why don't you just see the final result at the end with `$mech->content` ?

Comment: No not the same, that just views it in the terminal as raw html. I want the formatted graphical display.

Comment: So use the _brian d foy_ solution.

Answer (score 1):

There's [WWW::Mechanize::Firefox](http://www.metacpan.org/module/WWW::Mechanize::Firefox) if you want to do the same thing in a browser. I wrote [Controlling Firefox from Perl](http://perltricks.com/article/138/2014/12/8/Controlling-Firefox-from-Perl).

Comment: Am I able to navigate through a number of pages without opening a browser, and then when I reach the final page in the chain, open a browser only for that last page?

Comment: Possibly you can do that although I haven't. I've read about people doing it with headless systems and there is a way to take a screenshot of a page.